# How can I determine why a jQuery ajax $.post request wasn't successful?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I'm trying to determine, based on the result of this call, if it was successful. The `successFunction` doesn't get called, so I'm assuming it was not. How do I know what went wrong?

```
xmlRequest = $.post("/url/file/", { 'id' : object.id }, successFunction, 'json');
```

Do I use the xmlRequest object?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"/url/file/",
    dataType:"json"
    data:{ 'id' : object.id }
    error:function(request){alert(request.statusText)}
    success:successFunction
})
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use the $.ajaxComplete() and/or $.ajaxError() methods to attach function to those events.  I would also recommend using the Firefox browser with the Firebug pluging, you can get a lot of information about the requests and responses.

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work, i tried using the example on jquery's page with no success